# can i make fade in background color transition for transparent .png image?

Tags: jquery, css, colors, css-transitions, transition

can i make fade in background color transition for transparent .png image?
tired many method (with css and with jquery) but none of them work, some method only change background color without fade in / fade out,
do i need add script or something to use "transition"?

here's my code

```js
$('.a').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        background-color: '#ff0000'
    }, 1000);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        background-color: '#000000'
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
a {
  background-color: white;
  -o-transition:color 1s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition:color 1s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:color 1s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition:color 1s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  transition:color 1s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
}
a:hover { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="site-branding">
            <a href="http://lavinbylycka.com/" rel="home">
                <img src="http://lavinbylycka.com/images/logobrand.png" class="img-responsive img-center" style="">
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: @leo the lion sorry typo sir, i want exactly like this http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/xejsM/52/ or http://jsfiddle.net/dWCbk/, but for my image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.my-image {
  width : 100px;   /* only for test purposes can be removed */
  height : 100px;  /* only for test purposes can be removed */ 
  transition : 2s;
  background-color : transparent; /* initialize the default color without mouseover */
}

.my-image:hover {
  background-color : red;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lavinbylycka.com/images/logobrand.png" alt="Lavin By Lycka" class="img-responsive my-image" />
```

You can use this CSS below to perform your task. You were using `color` which is for the text, `background` or `background-color` better fits your needs.

Comment: thanks sir, now i know, i should add the class, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right lines, but `color` is the 'forecolor'. You want to use `background-color`.